# why is margin top not working on div?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am getting my head around bootstrap. At the moment struggling to get the margin on the bottom of the comboboxes group working this is the css:

```
.tableborder{
  margin-top:10px;
}
```

and the html:

```
 <div class="tableborder ng-scope">
        <!-- ngRepeat: person in list |filter:search | filter:birthPlace | orderBy:sorter -->
        <table class="table-striped ng-scope" ng-repeat="person in list |filter:search | filter:birthPlace | orderBy:sorter">
```

Also another thing: why is the table at the bottom not centred:

```
.tableborder td,th{
  text-align: center;
}
```

Here is a link to the code:
http://plnkr.co/edit/0gUyVQIC2RijsCQK8qGy?p=preview

Comment: What is it that you want to do? What is the intended UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your plunker you have added the link to the css as if you are linking to a javascript file. You need to change it to:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```